# 3 layer li ul menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, html-lists, layer

I want to create a 3 layer li ul menu but the 3 layer is covering the second layer. Can someone help me to align the 3 layer just right next to the second layer?

I very much appreciate your comments!

Best,
W

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<HEAD><title>bla</title>

<style type="text/css">
ul {
font-family : Arial, Verdana;
font-size : 18px;
font-weight: bold;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
list-style : none;
z-index: -10;
}
ul li {
display : block;
position : relative;
float : left;
}
li ul {
display : none;
position : relative;
}
ul li a {
display : block;
text-decoration : none;
color : #ffffff;
border-top : 0 solid #ffffff;
padding : 6px 25px 6px 25px;
background : #033a96;
margin-left : 0;
white-space : nowrap;
}

ul li a:hover {
background : #9092c7;
}
li:hover ul {
display : block;
position : absolute;
z-index: 10;
}
li:hover li {
float : none;
font-size : 14px;
z-index: 10;
}
li:hover a {
background : #9092c7;
z-index: 10;
}
li:hover li a:hover {
background : #033a96;
z-index: 10;
}

</style>
</head>


<body >

            <TABLE  border=0 align="center" cellPadding=0 cellSpacing=0 valign="top">
              <TBODY valign="top">
              <TR valign="top">

             <TD width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

                 <TABLE height=19 valign="top" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" border=0>
                 <tr>
                 <td height=35 bgcolor="#033a96" > 
                 <div id="menu_about" style="position: relative; z-index: 10;"> 
                 <ul id="menu">
                    <li ><a class="link" href="index.htm" >Layer 1</a>
                    <ul>
                            <li ><a href="#">Layer 2 blblb</a></li>
                            <li ><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
                            <ul >
                                <li ><a href="#">Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 </a></li>
                                <li ><a href="#">Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 </a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>


                    <li><a class="link" href="#about" data-link="second">Layer 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li ><a href="#">Layer 2 blblb</a></li>
                            <li ><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
                            <ul >
                                <li ><a href="#">Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 </a></li>
                                <li ><a href="#">Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 </a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </div>
                </td> 
                </tr>
                </TABLE>                  

            </TD>
            </TR>
            </TBODY>
            </TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

I very much suspect you are using a WYSIWYG (like Dreamweaver) to generate your code? 
Two notes on this:

- Try to avoid inline styling
- Don't use table-based lay-out except for tabular data. Use divs, nav, footer, header, and aside elements

For your solution:

1. Removed all the z-indexes, they aren't needed
2. You forgot to nest the 3rd level ul's in a second level li
3. Try to set properties like font-size on normal state elements, not hover (doesn't change)
4. I would advise naming your ul's and li's, or at least putting them in a logical order in your css, because this is quite messy.

**The most important part that fixes your navigation is this css I added**

```css
ul li ul li ul {
margin-left: 100%;
}
```

It sets your nested ul's and their children's margin to the parent div's width.

So here is your complete new css:

```css
ul {
font-family : Arial, Verdana;
font-size : 18px;
font-weight: bold;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
list-style : none;
}
ul li {
display : block;
float : left;
}
ul li ul li ul {
margin-left: 100%;
}
li ul {
display : none;
}
ul li a {
display : block;
text-decoration : none;
color : #ffffff;
padding : 6px 25px 6px 25px;
background : #033a96;
white-space : nowrap;
}

ul li a:hover {
background : #9092c7;
}
li:hover ul {
display : block;
position : absolute;
}
li li {
float : none;
font-size : 14px;
}
li:hover a {
background : #9092c7;
}
li:hover li a:hover {
background : #033a96;
}
```

And your html (only the relevant part):

```html
<div id="menu_about" style="position: relative; z-index: 10;">
<ul id="menu">
    <li ><a class="link" href="index.htm" >Layer 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Layer 2 blblb</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Layer 2</a>
                <ul >
                    <li ><a href="#">Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 </a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#">Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#about" data-link="second">Layer 1</a>
        <ul>
        <li ><a href="#">Layer 2 blblb</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Layer 2</a>
            <ul >
                <li ><a href="#">Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 </a></li>
                <li ><a href="#">Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 Layer 3 </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Layer 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```